# How to data bind from other component

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am new to vue and I am wondering how to data-bind from one component to another.

```js
export default {
  name: 'dashboard-sidebar',
  methods: {
    monthChange: function (event) {
      var selectedMonth = $("#sel1").val();
      this.$root.$emit('changed', selectedMonth);

    },
    dashboardReportsChange(value){
      var selectedDashboard = value;
      this.$root.$emit('click', selectedDashboard);

    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the value of the variables I declare and data-bind it into another component in my app.

```js
export default {
  components:{
    dashboardsidebar
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('changed', (selectedMonth) => {
      console.log(selectedMonth);
    })
    this.$root.$on('click', (selectedDashboard) => {
      console.log(selectedDashboard)
    })

  }
}
```

This is my other component.

Comment: You can check vuex for state management https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind data between components. What you can do;

1. You can use [`VueX`](https://vuex.vuejs.org), which is also what I would recommend.
2. If components have parent-child relation, you can use [`props`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props).
3. Or you can use Events or a global EventBus and create methods for accessing the data in the specific component.

I hope this helps you somehow.